# Date in IST in SQL Server

Tags: sql-server-2008, datetime

My server is hosted in US or so with some other time zone. Is there an option to get the current date in SQL Server in Indian Standard Time.

```
select getdate()
```

What should I write to get the current time in India(or some other country as such).

Answer (score 22, accepted):

You should use the [`DATETIMEOFFSET`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb630289.aspx) datatype which includes the timezone, and the [`SWITCHOFFSET`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb677244.aspx) method to switch between timezones. Also: to get the current time, use `SYSDATETIMEOFFSET()` instead of `GETDATE()`

```
-- gets current date/time in the current timezone
SELECT 
SYSDATETIMEOFFSET()

-- get the current date/time in your preferred timezone +05:30 UTC being Indian Std. Time
SELECT 
SWITCHOFFSET(SYSDATETIMEOFFSET(), '+05:30')
```

Comment: hi @marc_s can you just let me know how to drop off the time zone offset value from result. Now i get it as 10/3/2011 4:07:31 PM +05:30. I don't need +05:30 in result

Comment: @AkhilKNambiar: just use `CAST(SWITCHOFFSET(SYSDATETIMEOFFSET(), '+05:30') AS DATETIME)` and that should do it

Answer (score 0):

According to [this link](http://www.happyzebra.com/timezones-worldclock/India-and-USA.php) India's time is `9:30 hours ahead` from US. So in-order to get the Indian time, you need to add `9.30 hours` to US time.

```
SELECT DATEADD(hh,9.30,getdate())
```

Comment: In SQL Server 2008, it would be more advisable to use `DATETIMEOFFSET` which includes the timezone, and `SWITCHOFFSET` to switch date/time between timezones...

Comment: Dateadd hh with 9.30 doesn't work. Its should be n with 570 where n is for mins and 9*60 + 30 = 540

Comment: @marc_s: thanks for the information, its nice to learn new stuffs!