# How to convert sql server time to IST time in sql?

Tags: sql-server-2008

I'm trying to convert server date time to IST

I have tried the query below:

```
SELECT Convert(varchar(100), getdate())
```

But am unable to convert to IST Time Format.

Comment: `GETDATE()` is based on the local server settings... perhaps you mean `SYSUTCDATETIME()`

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Date in IST in SQL Server](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7633456/date-in-ist-in-sql-server)

Answer (score 0):

The only other option, assuming you aren't meaning `SYSUTCDATETIME()` could be this...

```
SELECT
   CAST(DATEPART(DAY,GETDATE()) AS VARCHAR(2)) 
   + '-' 
   + CAST(DATENAME(MONTH,GETDATE()) AS VARCHAR(3)) 
   + '-' 
   +CAST(DATEPART(YEAR,GETDATE()) AS VARCHAR(4))
```

**RETURNS**

```
23-Aug-2017
```

**OR...**

```
SELECT REPLACE(CONVERT(CHAR(11),GETDATE(), 106),' ','-') + ' ' + CAST(CAST(GETDATE() as TIME) AS VARCHAR(8))
```

**RETURNS**

```
23-Aug-2017 08:10:55
```